# Adding a graph in beamer poster

Tags: beamer, graphics, posters

I am trying to put a graph in a beamer poster. The problem (as you can see from the picture) is that the text overlaps in annoying ways. I was wondering whether there is a way to reduce everything proportionally so the text doesn't overlap so much. I've had the same problem with a parse tree in the same poster and I had to simply insert it as an image, but I was wondering whether there is a better way.

Here is a minimal working version:

```
% document class
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table,final]{beamer}

\setlength{\leftmargini}{4em}

\fboxsep=0pt

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% beamerposter package
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

%% standard packages
\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx,multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\graphicspath{{./plots/}}
\floatsetup[figure]{font={footnotesize,sf}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% document body %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{} 
\vskip-1.5cm{}

\begin{columns}[t]
\hspace{0.5ex}

\begin{column}{.48\linewidth}

\begin{block}{Model I}

\begin{minipage}{100ex}
\input{plots/plot_literal.pdf_tex}
\end{minipage}

\end{block}

\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong in all sorts of ways]

(Here is the link to the [.pdf](http://fileshare.link/fc197af26ba5c405/plot_literal.pdf_tex) and [.pdf_tex](http://fileshare.link/7bc5fd1d987fe0f3/plot_literal.pdf) files)

Comment: If your image is `pdf` image and has a lot of white space around it, you can clip it with `\includegraphics[trim=2cm 1cm 3cm 2cm, clip]{fig.pdf}`, where the sequence of numbers refers to left, down, right and top sides.

Comment: No the image is the right size (i.e. it takes the whole page, the problem is with the way it is imported in the main .tex (because the text in the image overlaps in annoying ways)

Comment: use a smaller font size for the image

Comment: or increase the image size by changing the `\svgwidth`

Comment: BTW: you could increase your chances to get an answer by including all necessary code in your question and not limiting the number of people how can help you to a) ones that are willing to follow links to external files and b) ones without add blocker

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

- either use a smaller font size for image

  ```
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \tiny
  \input{plots/plot_literal.pdf_tex}
  \end{minipage}
  ```
- make the image larger to match the font size you are currently using

  ```
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
  \input{plots/plot_literal.pdf_tex}
  \end{minipage}
  ```

(you'll have to experiment with the fontsize or svgwidth as I could not test with your files as they are hidden on some third party site that does not like add blocker...)

---

Off-topic: you don't need `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.